# mongoose how to pass extra parameter in exec callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, callback

I have the following loop:

```
params = ['Thing', 'AnotherThing', 'AnotherThingAgain'];
for (i in params){
    MyModel.find(....).exec(function(err, data){
     // do some stuff here
   });
}
```

So, when my request is executed, I want to use `params[i]` in the callback function. The problem is the request seems to be executed asynchronously so `params[i]` always take the last value of my array (`'AnotherThingAgain'` here).

How can I pass an extra parameter to that callback function in the purpose of using it in the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use closure:

```
const params = ['Thing', 'AnotherThing', 'AnotherThingAgain'];

params.forEach((param, i) => {
    MyModel.find(....)
    .exec((err, data) => {
     // do some stuff here with param or i
    });
});
```

Example with Promise:

```
// Some function to run on param
function searchParam(param) {
    return MyModel.find({
        param: {$eq: param},
    })
    .then((result) => {
        // For eaxmple combine result with param...
        return {
            peram,
            result,
        };
    });
}

const params = ['Thing', 'AnotherThing', 'AnotherThingAgain'];

Promise.all(params.map(searchParam))
.then((items) => {
    // items is array of param, result pairs
    items.forEach(({param, result}) => {
        console.log(param, '=>', result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Pasha, Thanks it works! it was just a context problem at least!

Comment: In what sense is this a closure? Anyway, this is not the "simplest" way, which would be to say `for (let i in params`.

Comment: @torazaburo For me this way is the simplest because it could be transformed into `Promise.all(params.map(function (param, i) { return Model.find().exec(); ...`